# Financial support proof for France Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, france, paperwork, proof-of-funds

I am planning to apply for France Schengen visa soon. This is 9 days total (including travel). They need my current account statements for the last 3 months.

Reg the proof of financial status, the minimum balance for me works out to be 65*9 = 585 euros say 600 euros.

My question is : 
Do I have to have this minimum balance amount (600 euros) on ***each day*** in the last 3 months OR is it only that I must have this amount as balance only on the most recent statement? The reason I ask this is that on certain days during the last 3 months - my balance on current account got less than the minimum needed, but the most recent balance is quite more than this.

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of any rules or guidelines requiring a specific balance on each day of the past three months but the [Handbook for the processing of visa application and the modification of issued visas](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf) also lists salary slips or certificate of employment as ways to prove sufficient means and then includes this:

> Consulates should be aware that, in some countries, a loan may be obtained in cash just for the purpose of presenting the equivalent of the requested means of subsistence to the 
>   consulate and the cash is returned when the visa application has been submitted. In such 
>   countries, consulates may refuse to accept presentation of cash as proof of means of 
>   subsistence.

I suppose bank statements over three months are mainly a way to ensure that you obtained the required funds in a legitimate way and did not simply put money on your account to make it look good for the application. Having a regular income and stable situation to return to would also make you less likely to stay illegally in the Schengen area after your visit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the required amount in your bank at the time you apply for your visa then there should not be any problem whether your had less than required amount a month before or so. The prime reason of presenting the bank statement to the embassy is that you have the required amount in your bank at the time you plan your visit and you can bear your expenses at your own.